# connection failure

Tags: дефект

Успел увидеть такую ошибку вместо двух страниц, но вскоре всё заработало, хотя и не всегда. При обновлении одной из страниц ошибка повторилась, а при следующем - пропала. Ещё воспроизвелось на второй ссылке при переходе из этого вопроса. Что это такое?

[image: скриншот]

[image: скриншот http-запроса]

Сами ссылки:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/2155500?noredirect=1
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/2155502?noredirect=1

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359524/865952

Comment: Тоже самое видел только что.

Comment: Ну может немного затянулась перезагрузка бэкенда, ну бывает)